# How to Inset a legend in GeoGraphics with Scaled LegendMarkerSize?

Tags: legending, scaling, geographics

I have a [`GeoGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics.html) where I am using [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html) in [`PointSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PointSize.html) to include *size* information.  I want to `Inset` a [`PointLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PointLegend.html) that describes the sizes of the points.

Outside of `GeoGraphics` I can do this by specifying the sizes directly using the [`LegendMarkerSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendMarkerSize.html) option. For example:

```
PointLegend[
 ConstantArray[Black, 4], {"Size1", "Size2", "Size3", "Size4"},
 LegendLabel -> "Info",
 LegendMarkerSize -> Range[12, 20, 2],
 LegendFunction -> "Panel"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, when I try this method with `Scaled` and [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) the points in the legend do not scale to the expected size.

```
GeoGraphics[
 MapIndexed[{PointSize[Scaled[0.02 First@#2]], 
     Point@GeoPosition@#1} &]@({35, -95} + {#, -#} & /@ Range[.1, .4, .1]),
 Epilog -> {
    Inset[
    PointLegend[
     ConstantArray[Black, 4], {"Size1", "Size2", "Size3", "Size4"},
     LegendLabel -> "Info",
     LegendMarkerSize -> Scaled /@ Range[.02, .08, .02],
     LegendFunction -> "Panel"]]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How do I get the legend to display points at the correct scaled sizes?

Answer (score 2):

WRI provided the below workaround as it seems `GeoGraphics` does not yet have full legend support.

```
Manipulate[
 im = GeoGraphics[
   MapIndexed[{PointSize[Scaled[0.02 First@#2]], 
       Point@GeoPosition@#1} &]@({35, -95} + {#, -#} & /@ Range[.1, .4, .1]),
   Epilog -> {
     Inset[
      PointLegend[
       ConstantArray[Black, 4], {"Size1", "Size2", "Size3", "Size4"},
       LegendLabel -> "Info",
       LegendMarkerSize -> scale2 scaling  Range[.02, .08, .02],
       LegendFunction -> "Panel"],
      {Left, Bottom}, {Left, Bottom}]},
   ImageSize -> scaling 350],
 {scaling, 1, 2}, {{scale2, 500}, 100, 1000}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This allows you to dynamically adjust `LegendMarkerSize` by eye until the size of the points on the map match the size of the points in the legend. `im` is updated to contain the `GeoGraphics`. It is not very useful for automation but will work for one off plots. Fingers are crossed for full legend support in future.